# The same partial behaves different in two identical applications

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have two identical applications in terms of gems, *.js and *.css files.
The edit view uses in both cases the same _form partial.

Here it is.

```
<%= simple_form_for @assessment do |f| %>
  <% if @assessment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@assessment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this assessment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @assessment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= f.input :question, label: 'Question' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= f.input :answer, label: 'Answer' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Save'%>
    <%= f.button :button, 'Reset', :type => 'reset', :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

I cannot understand why in the first app the input field is rendered next to the label field, but in the second app the same input field is rendered below the label field?

I am not using any bootstrap or similar.

Here is my `application.js` file, for both apps:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I have one single CSS/SCSS file, `scaffolds.scss`, identical for both apps, here it is:

```
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

p, ol, ul, td {
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

pre {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

a {
  color: #000;

  &:visited {
    color: #666;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}

div {
  &.field, &.actions {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

#notice {
  color: green;
}

.field_with_errors {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
}

#error_explanation {
  width: 450px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;

  h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: -7px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #c00;
    color: #fff;
  }

  ul li {
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: square;
  }
}
```

The file `application.html.erb` is the same for both apps, except the `title`, here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>LeviTest02</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

What I am missing here?

Inspecting the page rendered I found that the HTML is not the same in both cases.
Here is the HTML in app 1 which is rendering the input field correctly next to the label:

```
<input class="string optional" type="text" value="Yes" name="assessment[answer]" id="assessment_answer">
```

And here is the same line of HTML code in app 2 where the input field is rendered below the label:

```
<input class="string optional" maxlength="255" size="255" type="text" value="Yes" name="assessment[answer]" id="assessment_answer">
```

This line as supplementary parameter `maxlength="255"` which I have no clue how it is added there.

Comment: Everything is the same, including same browser version? I would inspect the elements and look at the css classes in the console.

Comment: Yes, I am running both apps using the Safari browser.

Comment: And I am getting the same strange behaviour when running both apps with the Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Using the chrome dev tools, and inspecting the styles on the elements, should reveal the difference, and where it is coming from.

Comment: I did so and I found the difference in the HTML generated. I will update the question to provide the HTML.

Comment: I just updated the question with the HTML extracted from the Inspector.

Comment: OK, I found the problem, thanks for the advise. I was missing the file simple_form.rb in the folder config/initializers for the second app. Once I copied the missing file there the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a file missing in the second app under the folder `config/initializers`.
Once the file `simple_form.rb` was added the the server restarted the problem disappeared.
Many thanks for the hints received.

Comment: Check out something like BeyondCompare if you're ever trying to figure out differences in files/folders. Would've been very useful and made it easy to see the cause of this issue.